# Why does my ViewController not present another SKScene after reopening it?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

so right now I'm programming a game and I'm experiencing an issue I didn't really found a solution for. I'll try to describe it for you.

So, in order to be able to explain my problem better, I created a schematic drawing for you guys:

[image: Schematic drawing]

Now here's the problem: I got two View Controller, one is called `MenuVc`, the other one is called `GameVC`. In `GameVC` I have a `SKView` that shows a specific `SKScene` when `didMoveToView` is called, named `GameScene`. `GameScene` has a `didBeginContact` method, which will then move to the other `SKScene` the `SKView` has, called `GameOverScene`, with the following code (Segue 1 in the drawing):

```
let reveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.5)
let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won: false)
self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)
```

From here, the user can go back to `GameScene` in order to restart the Game (Segue 2 in the drawing). On `GameScene`, there's still another button, which will allow you to go back to the `MenuVC` via a `NSNotificationCenter` event (Segue 3 in the drawing). The code for this is the following:

**In GameViewController.swift:**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "goToMenuViewController:", name: "GoToMenuViewController", object: nil)
}

@objc func goToMenuViewController(notification: NSNotification){

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuVC")
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
deinit{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

**In GameScene.swift, when the backButton was pressed:**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("GoToMenuViewController", object: self)
```

So if I now want to go back to `GameVC` using a Button on `MenuVC` (Segue 4 in the drawing), it all works fine. The `SKView` in `GameVC` shows the `GameScene` again, but when `didBeginContact()` is now called, it doesn't present `GameOverScene`. The function is called, I checked that, and it executes the code in it too, but it doesn't perform the segue (1) as it should. Do you have some ideas why and what I have to change? Is it something about deiniting when Segue 3 is called?

**Code for `GameVC`'s `viewDidLoad`:**

```
let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
```

**Code for Segue 4:**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameVC")
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be a concurrency issue. Are you sure you are always presenting the scene and view controllers on the main thread?

Comment: Also, please post the code for segue 4

Comment: @SantaClaus I added the code for the segue. How do I make sure if I present them on the main thread?

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...

Comment: But I'm not convinced that's your problem. You can try to make sure you aren't presenting view controllers on top of each other (and that you dismissed the old ones correctly). But that's all my ideas, so good luck!

Comment: @SantaClaus That actually was the solution.For segue 3 I wasn't dismissing the VC, but I was calling the MenuVC just like in Segue 4, so it was just a logical error and the VC did never dismiss. Thank you so much! Please formulate that into an answer so I can mark it as the solution and give you reputation.

Comment: Done. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are dismissing each view controller before attempting to present other view controllers.

I don't think UIKit really likes it if you try to present a view controller on top of another already being presented.