# SKScene can only be presented one time

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My problem is a bit specific. I have an UIViewController in which I have a button leading to another GameViewController. In the GameViewController I load a TransitionScene which shows the GameScene and we can play. Once the player lost, the GameViewController is dismissed

The problem I can't solve is the fact that after the first game, if I tap again on play the TransitionScene is loaded and showed but the GameScene is never presented and so I need to restart the app to make it working again.

Here is the way I present the GameScene in my TransitionScene

```swift
let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
let gameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") as! GameScene
gameScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
gameScene.gameViewController = self.gameViewController // Needed to dismiss the controller when the game is over
self.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution
Everything is explained in this post
[Why does my ViewController not present another SKScene after reopening it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352475/why-does-my-viewcontroller-not-present-another-skscene-after-reopening-it)

If u get the same problem, what is occuring is that after the first time, even if you dismiss the gameViewController you'll load a new UIViewController. I popped it from the navigationController in which they both are and it worked perfect !